# how to calculate RSSI in Veins

Tags: veins

How to calculate the RSSI value in Veins, the calculation method and theoretical formula look different, find the codes as follows, but did not understand, looking forward to help.

```
double recvPower_dBm = 10 * log10(s.getAtCenterFrequency());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are assuming is the "theoretical formula" to calculate RSSI. I am assuming you are asking about how Veins calculates received power based on transmit power of a signal. As of Veins 5.1, the calculations roughly follow a typical [link budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget) equation, taking into account transmit power, antenna gains, as well as various loss effects. One of these is path loss; the most simple path loss model, [free space path loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss), is being modeled by its [SimplePathlossModel](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimplePathlossModel.cc): Here, the attenuation is computed as [image: \left(\frac{\lambda}{4 \pi}\right)^2 d^{-\alpha}], which (for alpha=2) mirrors the formula of [free space path loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. How to set the antenna gain for transmitter and receiver in Veins-5.x ?